# Как изменить css строку через регулярное выражение?

Tags: javascript, css, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка css кода в javascript.

```js
 var section = 'header';
var css = 
`{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.top {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {

  .top {
    display: none;
  }

}`;

css = css.replace(/(.*){/g, `section#${section} $1{`);
console.log(css)
```

После replace всё встаёт как надо, кроме @media. Как изменить регулярку так, чтобы в $1 не входили выражения с символом @?

Comment: Может, [`.replace(/^(?!@)(.*){/gm, \`section#${section} $1{\`)`](https://regex101.com/r/W5EbKU/1)?

Answer (score 1):

Тут два варианта: либо не добавлять только к самому запросу (как Вам ответили в комментарии), либо не добавлять также ко всем правилам в секции запроса (и вообще, ко всему, что с отступами):

```js
var section = 'header';
var css =
  `{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.top {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {

  .top {
    display: none;
  }

}`;

document.querySelectorAll('pre')[0].innerText = css.replace(/^(?!@)(.*){/gm, `section#${section} $1{`);
document.querySelectorAll('pre')[1].innerText = css.replace(/^(?![@\s])(.*){/gm, `section#${section} $1{`);
```

```css
pre {display: inline-block; border: 1px dashed #080; padding: 10px 15px;}
```

```html
<pre class="first"></pre><pre class="second"></pre>
```